# Send Post Request in Excel with VBA on both Mac/Windows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-mac

I created a Auth API and I want to send post request with using VBA in Excel. Also, I want to this VBA code have to work both Mac and Windows.

Then, I created this code snippet.

```
Sub SendRequestAndGetToken()
    Dim objRequest As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim email As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim postData As String
    Dim responseText As String
    Dim jsonResponse As Object
    Dim token As String
    
    ' Set the URL
    url = "API_SERVICE"
    
    ' Retrieve email and password from specific cells
    email = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Authentication").Range("B1").Value
    password = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Authentication").Range("B2").Value
    
    ' Construct the POST data
    postData = "{""email"":""" & email & """,""password"":""" & password & """}"
    
    ' Create a new XMLHttpRequest object
    Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    isAsync = True
    ' Open the connection to the URL
    objRequest.Open "POST", url, isAsync
    
    ' Set the content type header
    objRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    
    ' Send the POST request with the data
    objRequest.send (postData)
    
    ' Get the response text
    responseText = objRequest.responseText
    
    ' Parse the JSON response
    Set jsonResponse = JsonConverter.ParseJson(responseText)
    
    ' Check if token exists in the response
    If Not jsonResponse("token") Is Nothing Then
        ' Extract the token from the response
        token = jsonResponse("token")
        
        ' Display the token in a message box
        MsgBox "Token: " & token
    Else
        MsgBox "Login failed. Please check your credentials."
    End If
End Sub
```

However, I got **ActiveX component can't create object or return reference to this object (Error 429)** error on `Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")`. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=MSXML2.XMLHTTP+on+mac+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: Maybe look at: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web which is Mac-compatible

Comment: This excel file will be downloadable by users. Therefore, when I use the package you suggested, will it be workable for other users or do users need to do anything additional to use the macro?

Comment: You import that library code into your workbook: it's not an add-in or similar.